# Error when I try to define a function for a return a penultimate element

Tags: scala

I need to obtain the penultimate element of a list in this way

```
def penultimate(list: List[Int]): Option[Int] = ???
```

I try

```
def penultimate(list: List[Int]): Option[Int] = {
 list match {
 case _ :+ list :+ _ => Some(list)
 case list +: Nil => Some(list) 
 case _ => None
```

but it is okey but if the list is empty, the code give me a fail in this try

```
it should "return None if there is no penultimate element" in {
    penultimate(List()) should be (None)
    penultimate(List(5)) should be (None)
  }
```

any solution with this

thank you

Comment: What does it mean _"give me a fail"_? This match never fails, because the last case always catches everything that wasn't handled elsewhere.

Comment: sorry the fail is with empty list not with list with one value

Comment: Again: the match _never_ fails, not for empty lists, not for anything else. The first two cases seem to be both wrong though, so I'm not actually sure what you're expecting. Also, where is the recursion? Can you provide a _specific input_ for which it "fails", and explain what you expected and what you obtained instead?

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you requested, the `List(5)` (i.e. `5 :: Nil`) matches against `list +: Nil`, and returns `Some(5)`, which is clearly different from the expected `None`.

The obvious solution should work just fine:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def penultimate[A](xs: List[A]): Option[A] = xs match
  case Nil => None
  case u :: Nil => None
  case p :: u :: Nil => Some(p)
  case _ :: rest => penultimate(rest)
```

Comment: but I need the same first line, I can't modify this line sorry. You can edit my code for the answer ?

Comment: @BorjaAlamo when you take this solution to your professor, do you not expect that you might have to be able to answer some questions about how it works?